# How can I use a Parsec parser which has a different stream type than another Parsec parser?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have a parser written with `Text` as the stream type, while by default the `Text.Parsec.String` module uses `String` otherwise.

How can I use the custom written parser (`Parsec Text b c`) in the context of `Parsec String b c`?

Essentially it seems I would need such a function:

```
f :: Parsec Text b c -> Parsec String b c
f = undefined
```

Although it sounds possible, it seems like it might be quite complex to do.

Comment: If this is really `Parsec` from the `parsec` package, then -- as far as I can see -- the first parameter to the `Parsec` type is the stream type, not the error type.  Are you mixing up `parsec` and `megaparsec`?

Comment: Hmmm yes sorry I wrongly assumed it was the error type. So this should be stream instead. Will fix shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's gruesome, but relatively straightforward.  The idea is to use the low-level functions `runParsecT` and `mkPT` to deconstruct and reconstruct the parser, bracketing it with adapters to modify the stream type of the incoming and outgoing state:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as Text

stringParser :: (Monad m) => ParsecT Text u m a -> ParsecT String u m a
stringParser p = mkPT $ \st -> (fmap . fmap . fmap) outReply $ runParsecT p (inState st)
  where inState :: State String u -> State Text u
        inState  (State i pos u) = State (Text.pack i) pos u
        outReply :: Reply Text u a -> Reply String u a
        outReply (Ok a (State i pos u) e) = Ok a (State (Text.unpack i) pos u) e
        outReply (Error e) = Error e
```

It seems to work okay:

```
myTextParser :: Parsec Text () String
myTextParser = (:) <$> oneOf "abc" <*> many letter

myStringParser :: Parsec String () (String, String)
myStringParser = (,) <$> p <* spaces <*> p
  where p = stringParser myTextParser

main = do
  print =<< parseTest myStringParser "avocado butter"
  print =<< parseTest myStringParser "apple error"
```

giving:

```
λ> main
("avocado","butter")
()
parse error at (line 1, column 7):
unexpected "e"
expecting space
()
```

**HOWEVER**, there are likely to be some serious performance problems here, unless this is being used in a small, toy parser.  The `pack` calls will take the entire incoming stream and convert it to a `Text` value.  If you are parsing from a lazy `String` (e.g., from a lazy I/O call), the first use of a converted parser will read the entire string into memory as a `Text` and pump it back out as a `String`; further calls to the same parser will re-pack the remaining stream as `Text` each time.  Switching to lazy `Text` won't really help, since `pack` still packs the whole input into the "lazy" `Text` value.

You'll need to run some tests/benchmarks to see if this performance hit is acceptable in your application.  Generally speaking, rewriting the `Text` parser (or seeing if it will compile with an abstract stream type) will be a better approach.

Full code example:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Text.Parsec
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as Text

stringParser :: (Monad m) => ParsecT Text u m a -> ParsecT String u m a
stringParser p = mkPT $ \st -> (fmap . fmap . fmap) outReply $ runParsecT p (inState st)
  where inState :: State String u -> State Text u
        inState  (State i pos u) = State (Text.pack i) pos u
        outReply :: Reply Text u a -> Reply String u a
        outReply (Ok a (State i pos u) e) = Ok a (State (Text.unpack i) pos u) e
        outReply (Error e) = Error e

myTextParser :: Parsec Text () String
myTextParser = (:) <$> oneOf "abc" <*> many letter

myStringParser :: Parsec String () (String, String)
myStringParser = (,) <$> p <* spaces <*> p
  where p = stringParser myTextParser

main = do
  print =<< parseTest myStringParser "avocado butter"
  print =<< parseTest myStringParser "apple error"
```